# System.BadImageFormatException for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

It seems I've somehow managed to corrupt my machine's .NET Core installation. I am unable to run any basic ASP.NET Core application.  Instead the following error occurs:

> System.BadImageFormatException occurred
>
> HResult=0x80131018
>
> Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> Source=`<Cannot evaluate the exception source>`
>
> StackTrace:
>          at CoreTest2017.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\CoreTest2017\CoreTest2017\Program.cs:line 23

This occurs regardless of which .NET Core version I run.  I haven't tried reinstalling anything yet (I don't have local admin rights on this work machine...) so I wanted to check here first to see if anyone has encountered this issue, especially as it relates to ASP.NET Core.

For clarity, this is a standard template for a web application.  The `Program.cs` contents are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace CoreTest2017
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `.csproj` markup (this is for an empty web project, which fails the same way):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: could you share that `Program.cs` with us?

Comment: have you stepped through the code and looked at the exception message and inner exceptions?

Comment: I never get to any code to step through.  The very first thing that happens is the application enters break mode and says "Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing)."

Comment: Are you compiling with 64bit?

Comment: Can you also share your project.json or csproj file?

Comment: Check .Net Framework version set on application pool of your application. It should be set to "No Managed Code".

Comment: @OfirWinegarten: I'm compiling for `Any CPU`. @natemcmaster: I've added the csproj (it's the standard one for an empty web project). @PankajKapare: I'm just running IIS Express, so I'm not sure how to update the settings to "No Managed Code" there.

Comment: Try to compile with target x86

Comment: Building with x86 and debugging the app causes it to immediately quit, but with no break this time.  Adding a `Console.WriteLine` in the very first line of `Main` and running `dotnet run` does not yield any console readout, so it is failing before reaching any code.

Answer (score 2):

> The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

This can happen when you are mixing x86/x64 bits. But as the assembly in question is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, I suspect the problem is that your NuGet cache is corrupted somehow. Try deleting the "%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" and rerunning restore.

If you still encounter the error, you may need to debug the host to figure out which assembly it is trying to load. Set the environment variable COREHOST_TRACE to 1 and run your app. This will produce detailed info on which assemblies your app is trying to load.

Comment: Thanks Nate, appreciate the help.  Unfortunately, deleting and restoring the NuGet cache didn't work (created a new project as well before restoring to ensure it was grabbing the new file).  I did enabled the trace info and I've uploaded the bit right before the failure in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zbecknell/81a18a6c7efda0966d69ecd8ef872be6).

Comment: The log file contains says it should be finding this file from "C:\Users\{userName}\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting\1.1.0\lib\netstandard1.5\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll"...can you double check this file is present? If so, also check it's not malformed. E.g., use `fc.exe` to compare it to the file in https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/1.1.0. (rename *.nupkg to  *.zip and extract).

Comment: Yes, the file is present and FC found no differences in the two.

Comment: Hmm, well I only have one more guess as I tried to repo it myself but couldn't.....the log you reported said it was using Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.3, but your csproj says netcoreapp1.1. It's possible the error is caused by mixing .NET Core 1.1 and 1.0 bits. Make sure you have the latest SDK (https://github.com/dotnet/cli) and clean your bin/ and obj/ directories.

Comment: That 1.0.3 is correct in that case, as I've been trying to run both netcoreapp1.0 and 1.1 default projects to see if either one would work, so apologies for the contradiction.  I also just tried downloading the latest SDK (1.0.0-rc4-004883) binaries and manually did a `dotnet run` using that specific `dotnet.exe` and after cleaning/deleting bin/ and obj/ with the same results.  This one is a doozy.