# Azure App Service threw System.BadImageFormatException after upgrading my app to Asp.net Core 2.1.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, badimageformatexception

I upgraded my web app to the latest Asp.net Core 2.1.1 and then I pushed it to Azure App Service from GitHub directly.  When I accessed my site, I got 500 and the log is showing the following

> System.BadImageFormatException:
>      at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) on the exception itself is saying “The exception that is thrown when the file image of a dynamic link library (DLL) or an executable program is invalid.”, while [others mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416327/system-badimageformatexception-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting) it's because Azure is using x86 version of the .net core.

Either way I could not figure out what exactly I need to do to resolve this issue.  Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

> If this exception occurs for an Azure Apps deployment when upgrading an app and deploying newer assemblies, manually delete all files from the prior deployment.
>
> **Lingering incompatible assemblies** can result in a `System.BadImageFormatException` exception when deploying an upgraded app.

Try to manually delete all files from the prior deployment.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-iis-errors-reference?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen when **your app dotnet core version** is not aligned to the **Azure Web app dot net core version**.
As an example, if try to deploy an app built with dotnetcore3.1 over a web application with dotnetcore3.0 runtime